# TypeScript 2.5 - Force typing functions in tsconfig.

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

If I do like this:

```
function add(x: number, y: number) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I would like to get an error that I have to specify a return type. Is this possible to do in `tsconfig.json`?

It should look like this to be OK:

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}
```

I can force variables to be typed by using `"noImplicitAny": true` but I can't find anything for functions.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Comment: This feels more like a job for a linter. I think [this rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/) could work, but I'm not sure I haven't used tslint ever.